# Distinct group eliminate only one result

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have almost same question as my previous

table 1

```
id    client_name   Group_id     
------------------------------
1     IBM               1
2     DELL              1   
3     DELL              2
4     MICROSOFT         3 
5     DELL              2
6     MICROSOFT         2
7     HP                3
```

table 2

```
id    group_name
------------------
1     Group1      
2     Group2     
3     Group3
```

Using query below.

```
SELECT Client_name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(group_name)) merge_group
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.group_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.Client_name
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

Would result from this

```
client_name      merge_group   
-------------------------
IBM                Group1
DELL               Group1,Group2
MICROSOFT          Group3,Group2
HP                 Group3
```

Now my question is I how can I eliminate those only one group name.

The result would be like this

```
client_name      merge_group   
-------------------------
DELL               Group1,Group2
MICROSOFT          Group3,Group2
```

Comment: just add `HAVING` clause. eg `....GROUP BY t1.Client_name HAVING COUNT(distinct group_name) > 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mysql having clause to eliminate grouped class with specific properties.

In your case you want to eliminate a grouped data based on the count of merge_group, you can do it as follows:-

```
SELECT Client_name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(group_name)) merge_group , count(distinct(group_name)) as num_groups
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.group_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.Client_name
ORDER BY t1.Id having num_groups>1
```